# ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am trying to have all access all courses in my courses.urls but when i trying running my server, i am getting this error message.

ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'courses.urls' from 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\jtalk_project\jtalks_institute\courses\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Here is my code

```
def course_list(request, category_slug=None):
category = None
categories = Category.objects.all()
courses = Courses.objects.filter(available=True)
if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    courses = Courses.filter(category=category)
return render(request,'courses/content/list.html', {'category': category, 'categories': categories, 'courses': courses})
```

def course_detail(request, id, slug):
course = get_object_or_404(Courses, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
return render(request, 'courses/content/detail.html', {'course': course})

here is the code for my url project directory

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('jtalks.urls')),
path('signup/', user_signup, name='signup'),
path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
path('course/', include('courses.urls', namespace='course')),
```

]

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Canh you share the `urls.py` of your `courses` module?

Comment: app_name = "courses"
urlpattern = [
    path('', views.course_detail, name="course_list"),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.course_list, name='course_list_by_category'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.course_detail, name='course_detail'),
]

Comment: it is `urlpatterns`, not `urlpattern`.

Comment: Wow, thanks error fix